# I cant figure out what type of Element is Google Pay interface

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, ui-automation, qwebelement

I am trying to run some tests with Puppeteer and this web element is blocking me, its not an iframe, it's not a new tab/window, it doesn't show on the DOM. How do i interact with this type of element? It has its separate DOM, but i don't know how to switch to it or interact with its elements.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5KI2.png)

In Selenium with Java, the same application instead of that weird element it opens on a new page, so it's easy to interact.